# Count number of values in array with a given value

Tags: php, arrays, count

Say I have an array like this:

```
$array = array('', '', 'other', '', 'other');
```

How can I count the number with a given value (in the example blank)?

And do it efficiently? (for about a dozen arrays with hundreds of elements each)
This example times out (over 30 sec):

```
function without($array) {
    $counter = 0;
    for($i = 0, $e = count($array); $i < $e; $i++) {
        if(empty($array[$i])) {
            $counter += 1;
        }
    }
    return $counter;
}
```

In this case the number of blank elements is 3.

Comment: Cellfish: array_count_values works, but the script which normally takes 1 - 2sec to execute took nearly 20sec!
Johnathan: array_keys did not work for this particular function.
Steve: array_reduce also works but not as fast as I would like.

Camomile: Simply by changing $value === '' to empty($value) that turned out to be the fastest way to do this.

    function without($array) {
        $count = 0;
        foreach($array as $value) {
            if(empty($value)) {
                $count++;
            }
        }
        return $count;
    }

Answer (score 36, accepted):

How about using [array_count _values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to get an array with everything counted for you?

Comment: `array_count_values()` is not reliable if the count is zero because only found values become keys

Answer (score 32):

Just an idea, you could use `array_keys( $myArray, "" )` using the optional second parameter which specifies a search-value. Then count the result.

```
$myArray = array( "","","other","","other" );
$length  = count( array_keys( $myArray, "" ));
```

Comment: This is a great alternative, especially if dealing with boolean values.

Comment: @SteveTauber or arrays as the search value :)

Answer (score 6):

I dont know if this would be faster but it's something to try:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($array as $value)
{
  if($value === '')
    $counter++;
}
echo $counter;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also try [array_reduce](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php), with a function which would just count the value you are interested in. eg

```
function is_empty( $v, $w )
{ return empty( $w ) ? ($v + 1) : $v; }

array_reduce( $array, 'is_empty', 0 );
```

Some benchmarking might tell you if this is faster than array_count_values()

Answer (score 2):

We use array_filter function to find out number of values in array

```
$array=array('','','other','','other');
$filled_array=array_filter($array);// will return only filled values
 $count=count($filled_array);
echo $count;// returns array count
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally for counting blanks only. 
Really depends on use case and speed needed. Personally I like doing things one one line.

Like the chosen response though But you still need a line to extract the data needed though to another variable.

```
$r = count($x) - count(array_filter($x));
```

Comment: Or use callback: 
count(array_filter($x, function ($v) {return '' === $v;}))

Answer (score -2):

```
function arrayvaluecount($array) {

    $counter = 0;
    foreach($array as $val){

        list($v)=$val;
        if($v){

        $counter =$counter+1;
        }

    }
return $counter;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your code in English as well by [edit]ing your answer?

Comment: Please explain your code to the OP and for the future readers.

Answer (score -2):

```
function countarray($array)
{        $count=count($array);         
         return $count;        
}        
$test=$array = array('', '', 'other', '', 'other');        
echo countarray($test);
```

Comment: $array=array('','','other','','other');
$filled_array=array_filter($array);// will return only filled values
 $count=count($filled_array);
echo $count;// returns array count