# how to count the number of items in a php associative array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array as below.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [item] => Banana Cream Cheesecake
        [item_id] => 3
        [product] => Desserts
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [item] => Banana Cream Cheesecake
        [item_id] => 3
        [product] => Desserts
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [item] => Banana Cream Cheesecake
        [item_id] => 3
        [product] => Desserts
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [item] => Banana Cream Cheesecake
        [item_id] => 3
        [product] => Desserts
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [item] => Milk
        [item_id] => 2
        [product] => Soda
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [item] => Banana Cream Cheesecake
        [item_id] => 3
        [product] => Desserts
    )
)
```

I want to print :-

```
Banana Cream Cheesecake = 5
```

how to do it?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317612/count-number-of-values-in-array-with-a-given-value

Comment: Since there is IDs you should use them to count item, the label may change while the ID is supposed to stay.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    if ($value ['item'] == 'Banana Cream Cheesecake') {
        $count++;
    }
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: I would hope for more re usability he would actually want an array of totals rather than just knowing how many of that specific dessert there are?

Comment: This answer is work faster than `array_count_values()` My code use something like this for 8 times. Spend total 0.22 milliseconds.
Then I change to use `array_count_values()` for once only this function spend 0.39 milliseconds.

Answer (score 5):

```
array_count_values(array_map(function($foo){return $foo['item'];}, $arr));
```

Answer (score 3):

Given an array like this:

```
$arr = array(array('item' => 'Banana Cream Cheesecake',
                   'item_id' => 3,
                   'product' => 'Desserts'),
             array('item' => 'Banana Cream Cheesecake',
                   'item_id' => 3,
                   'product' => 'Desserts'),
             array('item' => 'Banana Cream Cheesecake',
                   'item_id' => 3,
                   'product' => 'Desserts'),
             array('item' => 'Banana Cream Cheesecake',
                   'item_id' => 3,
                   'product' => 'Desserts'),
             array('item' => 'Milk',
                   'item_id' => 2,
                   'product' => 'Soda'),
             array('item' => 'Banana Cream Cheesecake',
                   'item_id' => 3,
                   'product' => 'Desserts'));
```

You could use [array_count_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) and get the count by its name

```
$counted = array_count_values(array_map(function($value){return $value['item'];}, $arr));
echo $counted['Banana Cream Cheesecake'];
```

Or modify the function to work with the item's id:

```
$counted = array_count_values(array_map(function($value){return $value['item_id'];}, $arr));
// The item_id
echo $counted['3'];
```

Answer (score 1):

print_r the array and count the number of occurrences of your cheese cake.

No, seriously, without more infos this is a solution ;)

```
$iCount = substr_count(print_r($array, true), "cheese cake");
```

Comment: thanks! Answers and conditionned by questions, I guess i might do myself differently in other contexts...

Comment: Did you change the string/array inside by what you need?

Comment: @Navdeep You should do `print_r($array, true)` so it returns the string and doesn't write in standard output

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @steve's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10604365/2093734)

```
$counted = array_count_values(array_map(function($foo){return $foo['item'];}, $arr));
```

This gives you an array with totals of each value for the `['item']` key.

For example, this is the array your example would return:

```
$counted = Array
(
    ['Banana Cream Cheesecake'] => 5
    ['Milk'] => 1
)
```

Then, to print it's just a matter of echoing that variable:

```
echo 'Banana Cream Cheesecake = ' . $counted['Banana Cream Cheesecake'];
//prints "Banana Cream Cheesecake = 5"
```

The advantage here is that you don't need to run through a for loop for each value you need to count - instead you have an array with totals for all values for that specific key.

Answer (score 1):

Today is more simple to do this.

Here is your array:

```
$products = array (
  0 => array (
    'item' => 'Banana Cream Cheesecake',
    'item_id' => 3,
    'product' => 'Desserts'
  ),
  1 => array (
    'item' => 'Banana Cream Cheesecake',
    'item_id' => 3,
    'product' => 'Desserts'
  ),
  2 => array (
    'item' => 'Banana Cream Cheesecake',
    'item_id' => 3,
    'product' => 'Desserts'
  ),
  3 => array (
    'item' => 'Banana Cream Cheesecake',
    'item_id' => 3,
    'product' => 'Desserts'
  ),
  4 => array (
    'item' => 'Milk',
    'item_id' => 2,
    'product' => 'Soda'
  )
);
```

Count items:

```
$counts = array_count_values(array_column($products, 'item'));

var_dump($counts);
```

[Demo Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/db679037663055c8fe20a4f833ede38fa3bcda12)

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Get an issue when dealing with numbers instad of just strings, due to the fact that substr_count takes also the keys, so I used just plain count instead of `substr_count` and worked fine.

```
$icount=count(print_r($_SESSION['id_bra'], true), $bran);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php
(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7, PHP 8)

count — Counts all elements in an array or in a Countable object

```
var_dump(count($array));
```