# count() returning wrong value

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the following code:

```
$row_arr=$_POST['row_driver'];
print_r($row_arr);
```

returns:

> Array ( [0] => d1 [1] => d2 [2] => d3 [3] => d5 )

but

```
echo count($row_arr);
```

is returning me a value of

> 1

Any reason why?

Here row_driver is an array being received through a form from a previous PHP page using hidden element property of HTML form. Also,

```
foreach($row_arr as $driver)
{
//code here
}
```

is returning:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in 
>        D:\XAMPP\htdocs\Carpool\booking_feed.php on line 36

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to count the number of items in a php associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604173/how-to-count-the-number-of-items-in-a-php-associative-array)

Comment: This looks like an indexed array

Comment: If you have one hidden HTML input, then wouldn't `$_POST['row_driver']` be a string? This would also explain the second issue you are facing, with `foreach()`

Comment: @JustBaron I am not sure of it being a string or an array but I have initialized the vavlue using the `<?php print_r($row_driver) ?>`. But what is the alternative solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is with the fact that `$_POST['row_driver']` is not an array.

If you have one hidden HTML input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="row_driver" value="<?php print_r($rows); ?>">
```

...then `$_POST['row_driver']` would be a string, e.g.:

```
$_POST['row_driver'] = "Array ( [0] => d1 [1] => d2 [2] => d3 [3] => d5 )";
```

, and therefore, your `count()` function results in 1.

This would also explain the second issue you are facing, with `foreach()`, where the function expects an array, but you are providing a string.

A solution would be to use a foreach loop for your hidden HTML inputs like this:

```
<?php foreach($rows as $row_driver){?>
    <input type="hidden" name="row_driver[]" value="<?php echo $row_driver; ?>"/>
<?php }?>
```

This would then turn your `$_POST['row_driver']` into an array.

Answer (score 1):

You might just store the count value in some variable :

```
$row_arr=Array('d1','d2','d3','d4');
print_r($row_arr);

$count = count($row_arr);
echo 'Your Count is:- '.$count;
```

Comment: It's returning the same value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the hidden field

```
foreach ($rows as $value){
<input type="hidden" name="row_driver[]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>">
}
```

Comment: but this is not the case with my array.

Comment: Can I see how the value of the hidden field is being set

Comment: `<input type='hidden' value='<?php print_r($rows); ?>' name='row_driver'/>`

Comment: While you are setting the value , remove print_r and then check and check in the console what is the value of row_driver being printed

Comment: @JustBaron solved my problem through his suggestion.

Comment: Yes..I saw that

Answer (score 0):

[PHP document](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

> expression
>
> ```
> The expression to be printed. return
>
> If you would like to capture the output of print_r(), use the return parameter. When this parameter is set to TRUE, print_r() will
> ```
>
> return the information rather than print it.
>
> Return Values
>
> If given a string, integer or float, the value itself will be printed.
>   If given an array, values will be presented in a format that shows
>   keys and elements. Similar notation is used for objects.
>
> When the return parameter is TRUE, this function will return a string.
>   Otherwise, the return value is TRUE.

`print_r()`  can use as special printing method to display all values in arrays and for associative arrays(more helpful for this).

**Associative array:**

[Associative arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp) are arrays that use named keys that you assign to them.

---

If you use `echo` you have print it with a array index. As a example `$row_arr[0]` or if you use for associative array instead of index, key is used. it may be string.