# is there a function to count multiple occurrences of different values in an array?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Count number of values in array with a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317612/count-number-of-values-in-array-with-a-given-value)

Let's say I've an array fruits:

```
$fruits = array("apple", "apple", "apple", "banana", "banana", "strawberry");
```

I want to transform this array into an array count:

```
$count = array("apple" => 3, "banana" => 2, "strawberry" => 1);
```

What would be the easiest way possible to archieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hy there,

You can use [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

```
<?php
     $array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
     print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>

    Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
$count = array_count_values($fruits)
```