# PHP search for multiple / duplicate values in an array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update a database with the amount of times a word is featured in an array. I found strpos to work as a function if it's only once - but if the word ('example') is used three times, I want the value returned to be 3 - not 'true'.

My current code:

```
$count = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item_name']);

    if (strpos($count,'example') !== false) {

    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET value = value + 1 WHERE id = '1'");

    if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
        error_log(mysql_error());
        exit(0);
        }
    }
```

I know I'm going about this the wrong way, but what would be the right way? Thank you!

Comment: Is `$_POST['item_name']` the array?

Comment: Yep. Sorry - should've specified that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317612/count-number-of-values-in-array-with-a-given-value

This should do the trick.

Comment: As a general note: avoid using mysql_* functions PDO is the answer: http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799

Comment: You're using m_r_e_s() wrong... you only use it on data that you're going to be using direcvtly in a database query string. Your "item_name" stuff never touches the sql query, so there's no injection danger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) finds all the pattern matches within the given string, it returns false if it finds nothing.

```
$matches = array(); // Not Used
$count = implode('_',$yourArrayHere, $matches); // Compresses array to one big string
$found = preg_match_all('/example/', $count); // Searches that string.
if($found !== false && $found > 0) {
  mysql_query("UPDATE table SET value = value + ".(int)$found." WHERE id = '1'");
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: PHP Warning:  preg_match_all() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given in [etc]

Comment: Ah $matches only became optional in 5.4, try adding a nonsense variable as third argument (or update PHP) `5.4.0 The matches parameter became optional.` Altered my answer with new variable.

Comment: This solution will update the table if the array contains a word like 'anexample' or 'myexamplehere', it needs word boundaries.

Also, regardless of the number of matches that you find, you're only updating the table record by 1, the question specifies it should be updated by the number of matches.

Comment: that would be your array of values to search :)

Comment: Good point umlat, forgot to add variable to query. As for word boundaries: user - do you want it to only match " example " or "examples" as well? (for instance)

Comment: The data will be like: example1, example2, random word, example3 - so ideally wherever it'll feature the word 'example' to add one to the total count to be added to the DB. (So in this instance, it'll add 3)  - copied over! :)

Comment: So literally '/example/' and not 'example' ?

Comment: The `/` are just there to say "this is the start and end of my pattern" it only uses the innards to find matches.

Comment: Great! Worked perfectly. Thank you so much. I feel like I've learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
$map = array();

for($array as $key)
{
    if(isset($map[$key]))
    {
        $map[$key] = $map[$key] + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $map[$key] = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

preg_match_all() should give you the answer that you're looking for.

```
$itemName = preg_quote(implode(' ', $_POST['item_name']));

$searchWord = 'example';
$numMatches = preg_match_all("/\b$searchWord\b/", $matches); //$matches is filled with the results

mysql_query("UPDATE table SET value = value + $numMatches WHERE id = '1'");
```

I'm not sure why you're calling mysql_real_escape_string() in your example. $itemName is never injected into SQL, so there's no need to make it SQL safe. I replaced the escape call with preg_quote(), which escapes regex special characters.

Comment: Sorry - Where would 'example' go? Would it replace all instances of '\b' as '\example' ?

Comment: My apologies, I'm having a long day :-). Now it should be right. You create a large string containing all the strings contained in item_name, and preg_match_all gives you the number of complete words (\b defines a word boundary in a regular expression) that match $searchWord.

Comment: Still getting this error with this: [13-Nov-2012 19:40:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  implode() [<a href='function.implode'>function.implode</a>]: Invalid arguments passed in [url] on line 58
[13-Nov-2012 19:40:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  preg_match_all() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given in [url] on line 61

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's definitely taught me about php.