# How to find the occurrence of each and every value in an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to find the number of occurence of every value inside the array.

Here is the array:

```
 $theArray = array(1,1,2,3,3,3,3);
```

Output should be like this :

```
 1=2;
 2=1;
 3=4
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1317628/3933332

Comment: Honestly i havenot been able to go further than this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `array_count_values()`

```
<?php 
$theArray = array(1,1,2,3,3,3,3);
$val = array_count_values($theArray);
print_r($val);
?>
```

This will output

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) -

```
var_dump(array_count_values($theArray));
```

**Output**

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(1)
  [3]=>
  int(4)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(1,1,2,3,3,3,3);
$vals = array_count_values($array);
echo 'No. of Non-Duplicate Items: '.count($vals).'<br><br>';
print_r($vals);
```

No. of Non Duplicate Items: 3

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 4

)
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. Very appreciated :)