# Counter Array in PHP

Tags: php

I want to write a function that returns a counter array. That is, given an array of integers `$A`, in which the integers are in the range `(0...$m)` it should return an array of size `$m + 1` in which each index has the number of occurrences of that index number in `$A`.

For instance, if:

```
$A = array(1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2);
$m = 4;
```

It should output:

```
array(0, 1, 3, 0, 2)
```

I'm wondering if there is a built-in function to do this in PHP.

In python it would look something like:

```
def counting(A, m):
    n = len(A)
    count = [0] * (m + 1)
    for k in xrange(n):
        count[A[k]] += 1
    return count
```

Comment: Maybe http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php?

Comment: No, write your own function. Also `array_count_values` can help

Comment: Might have your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317612/count-number-of-values-in-array-with-a-given-value

Comment: Any feedback for the answers?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$a = array(1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2);
$m = 4;

function counting(Array $a, $m){
    // Create our result array
    $result = array();

    // Make sure m is an integer for version before PHP 7, otherwise return an empty array
    if(!is_int($m))
        return $result;

    // Get the count of each occurence in the array
    $counts = array_count_values($a);

    // Loop through each number of m
    for($i=0; $i<=$m; $i++)
        $result[$i] = isset($counts[$i]) ? $counts[$i] : 0;

    return $result;
}
```

The result of `var_dump(counting($a, $m))`:

```
array(5) {
    [0]=>
        int(0)
    [1]=>
        int(1)
    [2]=>
        int(3)
    [3]=>
        int(0)
    [4]=>
        int(2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
function count_array($array,$m){
   // count values
   $count_values = array_count_values($array);
   // loop for $m times
   for($i=0;$i<=$m;$i++){
       // check if there exits a key in the array
       if(array_key_exists($i,$count_values)){
           $result_array[$i] = $count_values[$i];
       }else{
           $result_array[$i] = 0;
       }
    }
    return $result_array;
}

$A = array(1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2);
$m = 4;
$result = count_array($A,$m);
```

Out Put:

```
Array
(
[0] => 0
[1] => 1
[2] => 3
[3] => 0
[4] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

### New version:

```
$result = array_replace(array_fill(0, $m+1, 0),
                        array_slice(array_count_values($A), 0, $m-1, true));
```

- Replace an array of zeros with length `$m+1` with a count of the values of `$A` up to length `$m`.

### Original version:

```
$result = array_fill(0, $m+1, 0);

foreach($A as $i) {
    if(isset($result[$i])) {
        $result[$i]++;
    }
}
```

- Create a `$result` array of zeros with length `$m+1`
- Loop array `$A` and increment `$result` index of `$A` value

Obviously if you want a function just wrap code in:

```
function counting($A, $m) {
    //code
    return $result;
}
```