# Using substr_count to count multiple words in an array

Tags: php, arrays, substr-count

I trying to solve a bug in my code, i need to get the number of times words appear in a string. It's working fine with single words but i need it to only count the exact sentence (which may contain spaces)

```
$name = 'apple';
$words = array("apple", "apple juice", "hot apple pie");
$ingredient_count = substr_count($words, $name);
```

would result in 3, but i only want it to count the exact name, so in this example the result should be 1 because 'apple' on its own only appears 1 time in my array.

```
$name = 'apple juice';
```

would also result in 3 but should also be 1

Thank you for any advice

Comment: How about using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317612/count-number-of-values-in-array-with-a-given-value.

Comment: @Nigel please hammer these to prevent answers blocking the Roomba.

Answer (score -1):

You need to check items which are contained spaces like this:

```php
<?php

$name = 'apple';
$words = array("apple", "apple juice", "hot apple pie");
$count=0;
array_map(function ($item) use($name,&$count){
    if(strpos(trim($item),' ')) $count++;
},$words);

echo 'Count sentences: '.$count;
```